# Monotouch: How can I set the selected item(s) in a UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I've successfully created a UIPickerView and am using a custom ListModel tu supply the selectable items. But how can I specify which of the items should be selected when the view appears?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to call the picker view's Select method:

```
pickerView.Select(1, 0, true);
```

This will select the second row (index 1) of the first component (index 0). The boolean is for animating the selection or not.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectRow:inComponent:animated:).

Comment: Problem is here that this does not fire UIPickerViewModel.Selected method. Which mean model cant detect the change